How to validate query string values against user manipulation in Blazor WASM
I have a Blazor WASM standalone application that consumes a Web API authenticated via a JWT token. Since the nature of web assembly, the token, API endpoints, query strings and payloads are exposed to the client. I want to protect the server side Web API against parameters changes on calls (e.g. if the user copy the token to Postman and makes request changing query strings or payload).
I know this can be done manually validating every request parameters with service principals stored in the token, but I want to know if there is a correct or builtin way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance to everybody

if the user copy the token to Postman and makes request changing query strings or payload -> I think this should be a legal operation. As you know, we send https request from the client to the server, so that the payload is encrypted, that's why we don't need to encrypt the token. But if we obtain the token in the client machine, we can definitely use it in anywhere including postman. Users own client machine should be considered as a secure environment.
